# android - gridview (web.service)

Tags: android

I have a web service in c#.net and on my android form I need to pull data from this service and populate a gridview on android form. How can I do it?

Thank you,
Alina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decide on a standard way for communication between the device and your server .

then , get the list of the items and update the gridview according to its size , inflating all of the needed views with empty data . for each view , create and run an asyncTask that will query the server about more data about the item (like images,for example) and for both the [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) and [onPreExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) , check that the item matches the view , so that you will update the correct view.

also consider adding caching mechanism for each data that you received , to improve responsiveness and smoothness.

please watch **[this video](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)** for more info. it's about listView , but the same tips hold for gridView and all classes that extend AdapterView .